# Why there is a difference in Code Coverage results on SonarQube 6.7.5 Instance and on TFS 2017 Build definition

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tfs, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am building angular projects using TFS 2017 Build definition and after getting build it displays code coverage and test results result on the build summary. The Code Coverage result is displayed using cobertura tool and to publish code coverage result on sonarqube lcov file is used. 
But on TFS Build summary it displays code coverage as 64.46% for branches and 94.18% for lines and on Sonarqube it displays 87.7%.

Below are the configuration properties that i have specified in Prepare Analysis configuration task for Sonar TFS build.

```
sonar.sources=src
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.tslint.configpath=tslint.json
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts,src/Tools/**
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportpath=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.typescript.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/typings.d.ts,**/main.ts,**/environments/environment*.ts,**/*routing.module.ts
```

Is there anything that is missing or additional due to which there is a difference in result?

I have attached snapshot of the results for reference.

Code coverage result on Build definition

[image]

Code coverage result on SonarQube

[image]

Comment: The coverage tool you are using does not take into account the exclusions of SonarQube (that's expected), hence the calculation is different. If you configure the coverage tool and SonarQube to calculate using the same classes, the results should match.

Comment: It might depend on the type of analysis SonarQube does - is it Path coverage instead of line/branch?